# Any way I can SSH into multiple servers (from local to servA and then from servA to servB) using a local script?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, remote-server

I have two difficulties.

Q1.

I log into 'servA' using `ssh userA@servA` from local terminal, then from 'servA' I log into 'servB' using `ssh userB@servB` and cd into my working directory on 'servB' and execute 'programA' (servB cannot be connected from local). Every time I need to do this process manually and input my password twice (once for servA, once for servB).

Can I make the procedure above simply by running a bash script at local terminal?

Q2.

I want to copy data from local to servB and vice versa. Currently, I copy data from local to servA using scp and then from servA to servB. Is there a solution to transfer data directly between local and servB?

Comment: You haven't explained why ssh keys do not work for you.  If you don't know what they are, then read up on ssh.

Comment: @BruceK  The key works for me. What I feel tedious is to input the key every time. I got the solution here http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/key-setup.html

Comment: @Lee Good question! I solved Q1 once using ssh and keys, but for Q2 I could not find a simple solution.. I ended up doing it in two steps. (Though, the two step were automated in a script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest is to use the ssh connection to servA to setup a tunnel:

```
ssh -L50022:servB:22 user@servA
```

You can then connect to the ssh daemon on servB by accessing localhost:50022, the conversation is forwarded or "tunneled" to servB:

```
ssh -p 50022 user@localhost
```

or

```
scp -P 50022 /some/local/file user@localhost:/home/user/
```

You can automate that by putting it in a script. But then you have to take care that the first call (to setup the tunnel) does not block the script:

```
ssh -T -L50022:servB:22 user@servA &
scp -P 50022 /some/local/file user@localhost:/home/user/
```

Answer (score 2):

For the ssh hop, I used something very similar to this:

```
ssh -A -t hopserver ssh -A finalserver
```

from [here](http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html). I created a bash alias hop with something like

```
alias hop="ssh -A -t hopserver ssh -A"
```

so I could just type

```
hop finalserver
```

you can set access details up for each machine in your .ssh/config, and you'll want to put your ssh public key in .ssh/authorized_keys on each of the machines involved if you want to skip password authentication.

Hope that helps.

Comment: is it feasible to execute other commands between SSHs? e.g. alias hop="ssh -A -t servA; SCREEN; ssh -A servB"

Comment: `$1` is expanded when you define the alias; it does not parameterize it. `hop finalserver` works because `$1` was unset when you defined `hop`, and the "argument" to the alias is simply appended to the text it expands to.

Comment: Thanks @chepner - I've been using that alias for years to hop into a vpn and never realised it was working by side-effect not design :).

Comment: I've edited the arg out to make it clearer. Sure enough alias -p showed the argument was replaced with nothing at the time of setting the alias!

Comment: @Lee, it certainly should be possible to execute other commands, though I think something like screen would require a lot of messing about to attach terminals to it - might be worth just experimenting on that one if you're able?

Comment: @Lee This alias is already pretty much at the limit of what aliases were designed for. If you want to add more commands, use a shell function, or prepare some scripts on the first host. `alias hop="ssh -A -t servA 'screen ssh -A servB'"` might work

Answer (score 1):

In `~/.ssh/config`, specify a `ProxyCommand` which uses `servA` to connect to `servB`.

```
Host servB
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p userA@servA
```

Then `ssh servB` will log you into `servB` via `servA`. The `%h` and `%p` take the host and port number used in the original command, although this situation doesn't require anything so general.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work as-is for `scp`, though, but it should address the first question.

Comment: @arkascha I created ~/.ssh/config with the content you given. But I got this info: Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal. Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

Comment: Sorry, but if I am not totally mistaken then you confuse something here... This is _not_ my answer.

Comment: Modified using post found at http://blog.tanob.me/2012/07/17/transparent-ssh-tunnel-using-the-proxycommand-configuration.html

Comment: chepner, works perfectly! thx! @arkascha ahhaha, I'm badly myopic

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I think I read that blog post in the past but badly forgot the details, other than that `ProxyCommand` was involved.